# Altium: How to place the pin name inside rectangle in schematic library

Tags: schematics, altium

How can I make the pin name to be adjacent to the "Active X" mark on the pin?

In earlier version of Altium it was default. Here V.17.

[image]

In V.19 it is the opposite. In order to make the name go inside the rectangle I have to set the margin to -600mil

[image]

But as you see, it screws up the whole alignment.

[image]

Here on the 555 timer schematic it is perfect.

[image]

Comment: when you drag the pin, notice how there is a small 'x' like shape at the end of the pin - that is the side of the pin that is  used to anchor a wire. You want to make sure that side is external - and pressing space will rotate the pin 90 deg each time.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the "X" had to be snapped to the rectangle edge when I made the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Press the space bar (as you drag) to 'rotate' the pin. The designator and "X" will swap sides for orientations 180° apart.

I say 'rotate' in quotations because it's not quite a rotation so much as a "side of the IC package the pin will be placed on" setting.

Comment: No, that's the problem. The designator and "X" doesn't swap when pressing space. The designator just rotates around and always opposite to "X".

Comment: Thank you, but I misunderstood. I placed the "X" on the rectangle edge, as I thought it had to be snapped to it, as snapping a wire to an IO.

Comment: I've done that as well, before. The "X" should be outside the rectangle the distance of the pin. I've definitely tried to place it on the rectangle outline and been in your situation!